# ModuleNotFoundError, trying to use binance.websockets

Tags: python, websocket, binance

Hi I thought this would be pretty straightforwards but I can't figure it out.

It can't find binance.websockets for whatever reason even though it can find binance.client which should be part of the same package?

```
import config
import os

from binance.client import Client
from twisted.internet import reactor
from binance.websockets import BinanceSocketManager
```

Running this import code gives this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lucho/Documents/cryptoAPIs/binance/importconfig.py", line 6, in <module>
    from binance.websockets import BinanceSocketManager
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'binance.websockets
```

To get the library I installed with pip3

pip3 install python-binance

pip3 install binance-api

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The BinanceSocketManager is no longer in the websockets file. Change your import to this:

```
from binance.streams import BinanceSocketManager
```

This will fix the issue

Answer (score 6):

use this " pip install python-binance==0.7.9 "

Comment: Nice suggestion, but it didn't change anything, also no I'm not using heroku

Comment: pip install python-binance==0.7.9 use this

Answer (score 2):

If you look into the breaking changes on version 1.0.1 they mention they changes Websockets, so that is probably what you are hitting.

I would just reinstall the latest version "pip install python-binance" and use the up to date examples on their repo:
https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance